# Rails 4 app sometimes (unpredictably) makes requests with different (wrong) HTTP methods

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

My rails app sometimes (unpredictably) uses an undesired HTTP method/verb when making requests.

It happens all over the place. For example, when signing in, sometimes the appropriate POST request to users/sign_in is made and sometimes a GET request is made (which obviously fails to sign in and just reloads the page). Same thing for signing out: sometimes the appropriate DELETE request is made and other times a GET request is made (which leads to the infamous "Couldn't find User with 'id'=sign_out"). This happens with other resources and controllers as well, not just the User resource. So it's not a question of specifying the 'delete' method in my sign out link_to (which i've already done).

This happpens with link_to's and form_for's all over the place in an apparently (and frustratingly) random manner.

I was thinking it was some jquery thing, but i've got the jquery-rails gem and have required jquery and jquery_ujs in application.js.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this behaviour? **Please** help me.

Here's the network log and terminal output for successful and failed sign outs as an example:

Successful sign out:

```
Network log:
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Moved Temporarily
content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8

Terminal:
Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for 191.176.4.78 at 2015-10-31 20:32:56 +0000
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
```

Failed sign out:

```
Network log:
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Moved Temporarily
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Terminal:
Started GET "/users/sign_out" for 191.176.4.78 at 2015-10-31
20:36:03 +0000 Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
```

This shows me that on successful requests the content-type is **text/html; charset=utf-8** and is **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** on failed attempts. Any idea as to why the types are randomly different??

Here are some of my files:

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        '4.2.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.5.1'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',     '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.5'
gem 'turbolinks',   '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.2.3'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.5', '>= 3.5.2'
gem 'sdoc',         '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'static_pages#home'

  get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'

  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
  resources :users, :only => [:show, :edit, :update]
  resources :competitions, :only => [:index, :show, :create, :destroy]
  resources :attempts, :only => [:show, :create, :update, :destroy]
  resources :votes

end
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Sign in form: new.html. (Just as an example, cuz the problem isn't restricted to this form)

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email, class: "control-label", for: "inputEmail" %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "form-control input-lg", id: "inputEmail" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password, class: "control-label", for: "inputPassword" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control input-lg", id: "inputPassword" %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
      <%= f.label :remember_me %>
    </div>
  <% end -%>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "LOG IN", class: "btn btn-lg btn-success fill-width margin-top-small" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post your browser network log or console with this context?

Comment: @Rubyrider Ok, I added the logs to the question. They show me that on successful requests the content-type is text/html; charset=utf-8 and is application/x-www-form-urlencoded on failed attempts. Any idea as to why the types are randomly different??

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try `gem "devise-encryptable"`
May be it will solve the problem.

Comment: Well, the it doesn't seem to be a devise or user resource related problem. It happens with other resources.